# PHP Unable to execute Pytesseract in Python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, python-tesseract

I am using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send a base64 image to the PHP file on my Apache web-server. The image is always sent successfully. The PHP script executes a python script to extract text from the image (Using Pytesseract/Tesseract-OCR) and sends the output back to PHP. 
(Using Windows 10, if that matters)

The first two print statements are always returned in Postman but the third and fourth print statements do not return. The last print statement returns only when the pytesseract line is commented out.

When I run the python script by itself, all print statements return successfully.

Python (test.py)

```
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract
import sys

print "Print 1"
print "Print 2"

filename = "test.jpg"
#filename = sys.argv[1]
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("Images/"+filename))
print text

#Final print statement appears on POSTMAN only if the tesseract code does not run

a = "Print"
b = 1+2
print a, b
```

PHP (connection.php)

```
<?php
 header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

 if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){
    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $device_name = $_POST["device_name"];

    /*$image_name = $device_name.'.jpg';*/
    $image_name = "test.jpg";
    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'images/'.$image_name;
    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');
    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    $extracted = shell_exec("python test.py $image_name");
    echo $extracted;

 }

 else {
   echo "Failed :(";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Use the full directory path in the terminal call, `shell_exec("python [FULL PATH]/test.py {$image_name}");` the shell is executing in a different directory.

Comment: both files are in the same location. Test.py returns the print statements before the tesseract line, but nothing after it. The last print statement is returned only if the tesseract line is commented out..

Comment: Try and use the full Image directory path in the python file and see if you get a different result. Is it returning an error or anything?

Comment: Everything works fine when I run the python script by itself. The issue is when the python script is executed by PHP

Comment: My only theories are invalid directory or invalid permissions. Hopefully someone else can figure this issue out.